# using Enum for dropdownlist in databasefirst mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, enums, type-conversion, database-first

I have a field in Model(tablaMetadata) with  boolian field for gender as below:
(I work with database first MVC)

```
 [DisplayName("gender")]
 [Display(Name = "gender")]
 public Nullable<bool> EmpSex { get; set; }
```

I want to get value from EmpSex as "Male" or "Female" by dropdownlist , then convert it to boolean (for posting form to database).
I define Enum as below:

```
public enum gender
{
    Male=1,
    Female=0
}
```

I don't Know How can I use htmlhelper for Enumdropdownlist and convert string value of dropdownlist to boolean.
Can you help me to define dropdownlist for Enum and converting values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view you can create the dropdown like this

Create the list from `enum` like this

```
@{ 
    var genderList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender)).OfType<Gender>().Select(m => new { Text = m.ToString(), Value = (int)m }).ToList(); 
}
```

and create the DropDown like this

```
@Html.DropDownList("EmpSex", new SelectList(genderList, "Value", "Text", Model.EmpSex))
```

or

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmpSex, new SelectList(genderList, "Value", "Text", Model.EmpSex))
```

Comment: it's Ok, but I want to set a css class for dropdownlist. I change your code in this form:                                                       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Employees.EmpSex, new SelectList( genderList, "Value", "Text",new { @class = "form-control1 select2 ", style="width:100 %;" })).  but class dosn't apply. is it correct?

Comment: SO, you can add CSS by adding one more parameter in DropDownList `, new { @class = "yourCSS" }`

Comment: the correct code is `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmpSex, new SelectList(genderList, "Value", "Text", "----"), new { @class = "yourCSS" })`

Comment: I use these commands of Enum for "int"  field in sql and it was correct, but I use it for     " bit "     field in sql and I encounter to validation error message. can you tell me which property must be changed? I can't change    " int"    to    " bit".

Comment: You can try changing the definition of enum like `public enum gender : byte`.

Comment: I change it but the error is still remains.the message is "the value 0 is not valid for gender".